# Characterizing $\delta(0)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ using meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a compactly supported measure on $\mathbb{C}$ with total measure $1$. If I say that $\int f(z) d\mu(z) = f(0)$ for every *continuous* function $f$, then $\mu$ must be $\delta(0)$.

Is it possible to characterize $\delta(0)$ in terms of meromorphic functions? If I say that $\int f(z) d\mu(z) = f(0)$ for every meromorphic function, does $\mu$ have to be the point mass at $0$?

If yes, can we further restrict the class of meromorphic functions? (For instance, that its poles are not in the support of $\mu$)